# How to keep the values when after searching datetime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

- I have code: I want click button search from to date and the result value back datetime today. I need to keep the value date time.

  ```
  <input type="date" name="start" />
  <input type="date" name="end" />
  ```

```
@section Scripts{

    <script>
    $(function(){
        document.getElementsByName('start')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
        document.getElementsByName('end')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
    })
    </script>
}
```

Result i have :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl4Wz.png)

I want keep value when click search:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BISfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your form is a POST, you could do:

```
<input type="date" name="start" value="@(Context.Request.Method == "POST" ? Context.Request.Form["start"] : "") />
<input type="date" name="end" value="@(Context.Request.Method == "POST" ? Context.Request.Form["end"] : "") />
```

If it's a GET form, you could do:

```
<input type="date" name="start" value="@(Context.Request.Query["start"]) />
<input type="date" name="end" value="@(Context.Request.Query["end"]) />
```

Comment: dont work with your code